# Adding semicolon automatically after email address on text input field (javascript or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend, email-validation

## Question:

Whenever someone types in an email address in a text input field (correctly), and presses "enter" or "space" or "clicks" away from it, I want to automatically add a semicolon (;) at the end and "lock" that email address into place with a css style much like how yahoo email does to their email addresses (please refer to the screenshot below).

Similarly, StackOverflow uses this same "idea" for there tags (refer to screenshot below).

The difference is of course the front-end email validating that happens with the yahoo emails... If the email address has a correct format (name + @ + domain + extension) it wraps a nice silver background around the email address.. If however it is invalid, its wraps a mean red background around the *wannaBe* email address..

Is there a javascript and/or jquery plugin out there that exists or does someone have a good solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: We need to see some code. What have you tried so far? What problem did you encounter? How did you attempt to solve it? Can you post a live demo?. If the question is about finding a plugin, then it's not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: My objective here is to learn the proper way to do this and to see what other developers approaches are.

Comment: Learning the "proper way" comes with experience, that's why we ask that you try first. You can't expect to build something the "proper way" if you haven't failed building it the "wrong way"... Check this plugin though http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: I understand what your saying, but another view is: why re-invent the wheel? ;)  Thankyou for that link, I'm checking it out now